# Layout for all pages breaks app in NextJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, next.js

I have created NextJs app with `npx create-next-app` and tried to use my own layout. But it breaks the app and I really dont know why. I have these files in folders:

components -> `Footer.js`, `Header.js`, `Layout.js`

pages -> `_app.js`, `index.js`

styles -> `global.css`

`Node.Js` version is 14.16.1, `npm` version is 7.9.0

My `package.json` file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "10.1.3",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  }
}
```

And all other files have basic structure:

### _app.js

```
import 'normalize.css'
import '../styles/globals.css'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

### index.js

import Layout from "../components/Layout";

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <Layout >

        <div>
            <p>Paragraph</p>
        </div>

    </Layout>

  )
}
```

### Layout.js

```
import Header from "./Header";
import Footer from "./Footer";

function Layout({children}){
    return (
        <>

            <Header />

            <main>
            {children}
            </main>

            <Footer />

        </>
    )
}

export default Layout;
```

### Header.js

```
    function Header(){
        return(
            <Header>
    
            </Header>
        )
    }

export default Header;
```

### Footer.js

```
function Footer(){
    return(
        <Footer>
            
        </Footer>
    )
}

export default Footer;
```

I also tried to use layout in _app.js and it did the same.

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return(
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
      )
}
```

When I run `npm run dev`, server starts, but when I open `localhost:3000` in browser, it outputs an error in console and NodeJS server starts consuming about 4GB of ram.

The error is here:
[image]

Does someone know, what is wrong please?

Comment: From the looks of it your Header/Footer function components are calling themselves, you might've meant to return <header></header> and <footer></footer> instead in Header.js/Footer.js?

Comment: Yes, now it works..Thank you very much, I missed it.

Comment: Cool, I'll post that as an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it your Header/Footer function components are calling themselves, you might've meant:

```
function Footer(){
    return(
        <footer>
            
        </footer>
    )
}
```

```
function Header(){
    return(
        <header>

        </header>
    )
}
```